# Mounting GCS over FUSE

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

When mounting GCS through FUSE, `gcsfuse` does the file/files stored in the mount point are saved on the local disk file system (meaning does it consume actual disk space) or all data is stored directly to the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcsfuse` [downloads files to a temporary location](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse#downloading-object-contents), and keeps a cache. This is usually the right thing because otherwise you can use up all your available ram. If you want, you can prevent storing a local copy on disk by setting `--temp-dir` to a [ramdisk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66331/160746).